# Dynamic html editor

Tags: android, html, webview, editor

My program works like this:

I have a `WebView` that loads `assets/index.html`. In this HTML I have the "Download Button", and am using Ajax to call a function to download HTML from a website. Then, the user has an option to open this downloaded HTML file inside the `WebView` (using the `myWebView.loadUrl`).

How can I make the user allowed to "edit" the HTML? I want them to be able to select text and edit the colour/font/background/bold/italic/etc. and then save and it update the HTML file with the edited text (probably with tags, `<b><i>Edited Text</b></i>` in the place of the normal edited text?

I think it is better to use JavaScript to do this, then when they click "Save", it calls a method to save and the next time the user clicks to "See the html in the WebView" it shows the styled text.

How can I do this? Maybe using JavaScript/jQuery text Editor like this (http://jqueryte.com/demos)?

I don't know about performance issues, since every time the user edits something the application will have to parse from file, show in `WebView`, edit, than write again *full* text to the file.

Can anyone offer some examples? directions? or better advice?

Answer (score 0):

Add attribute `contenteditable` to your `<body>`

```
<body contenteditable='true'>
```

Now your `<body>` is editable.

Comment: thanks the answer, i will study this -> http://html5doctor.com/the-contenteditable-attribute/

but still the doubt about adding the support of bold/italic etc..

Comment: man, thanks so much, after you give me this new info about contenteditable, i tried new searchs and i found this: http://xing.github.io/wysihtml5/